# Ldap connection using axios in nodejs is not working

Tags: node.js, axios, ldap

I'm trying to connect to an LDAP server using Axios but it doesn't work at all.

I have already a connection, authentication, and user search using ldapjs npm module. But this module is not promised based and I prefer using Axios instead since it's promised-based.

The problem I'm facing is that Axios is not returning me any response, It only says. `Error: read ECONNRESET`

This is the code I'm using to make the request.

```
async function getUser() {
    try {
        const response = await axios({
            url: `ldap://${ip}:${port}/DC=${org},DC=${int}?memberuid,name,mail,objectCategory,telephoneNumber?sub?(mail=${mail})`,
            method: 'get',
            auth: {username, password}
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));

        console.log('res =>', response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

getUser();
```

Notes:

- I have tried using GET, POST methods none of them with successful results.
- I have tried passing those attributes as params but I don't have any result.
- This request connection is working using curl, it searches for the user that matches with the email provided in the filter and retrieves all the attributes listed. However, this request is not working with Axios.

What I think in my ignorance is that Axios does not support LDAP connections.

how can I solve this issue? any help would be enough. I just can't see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Axios only support HTTP and HTTPS URL's. You can use below npm package it will resolve your requirement.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldap-authentication